# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in PHP

Tags: php, csv

```
$fp = fopen('knights.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, ["Product Name","Product Code","Product Variance Name","SSP","Cost","Qty"]); //  <-error line
fclose($fp);
```

I am writing an csv file by using the above code. This working well in local server. but while i execute it in the remote server its not working.
Please give me some suggestions

Comment: What version of PHP are you running on your webserver? Probably a version that doesn't support the new array syntax that was introduced in PHP 5.4

Comment: Thanks Mark, its been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with an array:

```
$array = array("Product Name,Product Code,Product Variance Name,SSP,Cost,Qty");
$fp = fopen('knights.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $array);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your local server has higher PHP version thus it allows array declaration with `[]`. Use `array()` then.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) are some examples from PHP website.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is only available since PHP 5.4, use `array()`